# ASP.NET Identity: using a single context for asp.net identity in Class library project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I want to port in the ASP.NET Identity into my business logic as opposed to using it on the API Level. I created two database context which are the dbcontext and the identitycontext to handle this as I'm using a single database both for identity tables and other entities. The problem is that I want to use a single context in my BLL but it isn't working fine. I also tried to create dbcontext and identitydbcontext but only the dbcontext commits data into the database tables while the identitydbcontext failed to commit data into the identity tables in my single database. Does anyone have a solution to how I can achieve committing data using a single database context in my BLL class library project with my model in DAL generated using entityframework reverse engineering?

Data Access Layer
1. Context class generated by entityframework reverse engineering

```
public partial class TwiksDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    static TwiksDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TwiksDbContext>(null);
    }

    public TwiksDbContext()
        : base("Name=TwiksDbContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CommentEntityTracker> CommentEntityTrackers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContactCategory> ContactCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContactMessage> ContactMessages { get; set; }
```

2) Repository class where a single context for the entire project will be created

```
public class EfRepository<T>:IRepository<T> where T:class
{
   private readonly DbContext _context;
   private readonly DbSet<T> _set;
   public EfRepository()
   {

       _context = new TwiksDbContext();
       _context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
       _set = _context.Set<T>();
   }

   public void AddEntity(T entity)
   {
       try
       {
           _set.Add(entity);
           _context.SaveChanges();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw new Exception(ex.Message);
       }
   }
```

BUSINESS LOGIC LAYER
1. Custom Membership Class where all Identity methods are implemented in this project.

```
public class Membership
{
    private readonly IdentityDbContext _context;
    private UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
    //private UserManagerFactory
    public Membership()
    {
        _context = new TwiksDbContext();
       // _context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(_context);
        userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
        var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(_context);
        roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

    }

    public DbInteractionNotification CreateRole(IdentityRole role)
    {
        try
        {
            if (roleManager.FindByNameAsync(role.Name) != null)
                return DbInteractionNotification.EntryAlreadyExist;
            else
                return (roleManager.CreateAsync(role).IsCompleted) ? DbInteractionNotification.Success : DbInteractionNotification.FatalError;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return DbInteractionNotification.FatalError;
        }
    }
```

application configuration file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <configuration>
       <configSections>
       <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit        http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>

      <add name="TwiksDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SchoolTDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
       <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      </providers>
     </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: It is unclear what "isn't working fine" means when using single context

Comment: Thanks @raderick I want to try and make the application run on a single database context and the identity entities should commit data into my database. I want to directly implement the methods in the UserManager and RoleManager classes. This i want to make possible in my BLL class library project.